# Undefined Method error in Heroku, Ordering Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to order an array in descending order however Heroku is pushing an error back at me, claiming I have a undefined method.

My controller code currently looks like this.

```
def by_year_and_month
@bets_by_year = Bet.where("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at) = ?", params[:year])
@bets_by_month = @bets_by_year.where("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) = ?", params[:month])
@bets_by_month = @bets_by_month.all.group_by { |bet| bet.created_at.beginning_of_month }
@bets_by_month = @bets_by_month.order("created_at")


end
```

Unfortunately the last line is producing an error.

The Heroku Logs currently display this error when I load the page.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `order' for #<Hash:0x007f183dd33068>):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `group_by` method here converts your `ActiveRecord Relation object` into a `Hash` (at least on postgresql it does) and there is no `order` method for `Hash` which is the reason for your error.

If you local and production differ on this error it's likely because you are using a different db type between them.

Answer (score -1):

So, `all` forces the resolution of SQL results into a Ruby array and `group_by` converts that array into a Hash. As such, calling `order` doesn't make sense.

If you remove `all`, it should make `ActiveRecord` try to resolve everything in SQL.

Comment: But `group_by` will still be `Enumerable#group_by` without the `all`.

Comment: `group` is the synonym method in `ActiveRelation` to `group_by` in `Enumerable`.

Comment: ActiveRecord doesn't know what `group_by` is. ActiveRecord's `group` is very different than `Enumerable#group_by`. AR won't be able to send a block into the database to GROUP BY anyway.